# Java/Scala regex questions

Tags: java, regex, scala

Is there a better way to simplify my following code? Thanks!

```
 if (n.equals("000000000") || n.equals("1111111111") || n.equals("222222222")|| n.equals("333333333")|| n.equals("444444444")|| n.equals("555555555")|| n.equals("666666666")|| n.equals("777777777")|| n.equals("888888888")||  n.equals("999999999")) {
  // do my function
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to accept all possible strings with 9 digits numbers except the case that all nine digits are the same.

Comment: That's actually the opposite of what your current code does.  Right now, your function will run when the string is nine of the same digit.

Comment: Use `n.matches("([0-9])\\1{8}")`.

Comment: See @saka1029 code. Use it in inverse. If no match then it will be your desired string.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to accept all possible strings with 9 digits numbers except the case that all nine digits are the same.

Use this:

```
^(?!(\\d)(\\1){8})\\d{9}$
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/bH5tZ2/1)

So you code should be:

```
val regex = "^(?!(\\d)(\\1){8})\\d{9}$".r
if (regex.findFirstIn(n).isDefined)
    //true
```

Also this should work:

```
if ( n.matches("^(?!(\\d)(\\1){8})\\d{9}$") )
    //true
```

Comment: Thanks! What if in Java case? Do I need to compile the regex pattern?

Comment: Compiling is needed/useful if you intend to apply the regex multiple times like it in a loop for example; If it's used only once, then no need to !  The 2nd example work in java too...

Comment: I got the following error in the second one: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 10
^([0-8])(?1){8}$

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `999999999`, it should be `[0-9]` or `\\d`

Comment: And why matching `88888888` but not `999999999`?

Comment: @Toto well spotted, I really don't know what happened, he changed his requirements so many times that i'm not sure from where my answer came from :x

Comment: It's fixed now... I hope

Comment: Seems pretty fine for me now ;)

Answer (score 1):

It may be more efficient (and readable) to do it without regex:

```
def check(s:String) = s.size == 9 && ('0' to '9').contains(s.head) && s.forall(_ == s.head)

@ check("000000000")
res3: Boolean = true
@
@ check("000000001")
res4: Boolean = false
@
@ check("00000000")
res6: Boolean = false
@
@ check("111111111")
res7: Boolean = true
@
@ check("aaaaaaaaa")
res8: Boolean = false
@
@ check("")
res10: Boolean = false
```

Your descriptions contradicts your comment, so you may want to invert the result of the function.

Comment: Good approach. Love functional style. It would be great if you limit it to just numbers. No alpha.

Comment: @Saleem it accepts only numbers, as defined in range `('0' to '9')`. Or maybe I got you wrong?

Comment: Yes. You are correct it just accept numbers. I was pointing to test. Check("aaaa...  Most people glance first at output so get confused as question asks for one thing but answer is covering something else too. In real life your solution is solid. .